# Run method in other UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

On attached picture I show simple layout of a window. Can't figure it out how to launch a method in User Control in middle screen (see pic). What I want to achieve is, when I type in something in search box, list in currently visible User Control will filter to find desired phrase. Side buttons are to switch between different User Controls with different lists.
I know how to filter listview etc, just can't figure it out how to pass it to different User Control.

[image: Window Layout]

Comment: You can create DB and bind those to Search filter text box to filter the data in user contorl

Comment: Are you following MVVM ?